# Algorithm for searching for a key in 1,000,000,000 elements with the key being in the first n indices without n being specified beforehand

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

The question is as follows:

> Suppose you are given a very large integer array A with 1,000,000,000 elements, with elements sorted in descending order. However, only the first n elements contain data which are positive integers, but the value of n is unknown. The rest of the array elements contain zeroes.
>
> Give the algorithm for a method search(A,k) to search for a key k in the array A. It returns the index of the array where k is found, or -1 otherwise. Your algorithm must run in worst case O(logn) time.
>
> You may use binarySearch(A, k, left, right) that searches for k in A[left] through A[right] (assuming left to right is sorted in descending order).

The approaches that I have thought of so far:

1. Use a for loop to iterate from index 0 till the index containing the first 0 and compare against k. This takes O(n) time so doesn't fit the time limit.
2. Binary search on A itself. This takes O(log 1,000,000,000) time and exceeds the time limit.

I am kind of stuck here and unable to think of any other approaches.

What would be an approach that runs in worst case O(logn)?

Comment: Why you think that `O(log 1,000,000,000)` exceeds `O(log n)`?

Comment: Make your binary search skewed; like land at 1/3 on left side and 2/3 on the right side so moving from left to right it moves towards left faster than it moves to right

Comment: Could you share your "*Binary search on A itself*"? I doubt that this exceeds the time limit unless you did a mistake. Binary search is extremely fast and will find the relevant range in just a few steps (around 10 max maybe).

Comment: Share your code

Comment: It is impossible to answer your question since we can not test a solution against your constraints. The time limit is unknown, your code is unknown. Voting to close.

Comment: As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask]. Until then, you have not shown any code nor a problem with it. All we have is your interpretations, which makes a bad question.

Comment: @Sirko There's something odd with the question: It refers to "the first n elements" and then goes on with "O(logn)". IOW, "n <= 1000000000" and that is relevant to picking the right algorithm. It's this uncommon and/or misleading use of "n" which probably spooked many readers here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hi this approach is based on a modified binary search

1. Start at first index if matches return
2. Double the index untill value is found or you the end

   a) if Value is greater than k continue

   b) else if value is less than k BinarySearch(index/2, index, k)

So basically what we did is we narrowed down our search space by jumping forward, Like previous answer by nice_dev; But While Jumping we also checked if our value is in specific window if it is we stop jumping and binary search the last window

Comment: It may be helpful to explain why this approach is indeed `O(log n)`: the maximum index you get by doubling is `2n - 2`, and then you do a binary search on an array slice of size `(2n - 2)/2`, which is `O(log n)`.

Comment: @MoB. Thanks for adding that; The answer was already accepted when i added this 

Answer (score 0):

The idea here will be to first find the value of `n`. We can do a jump similar to concept of jump arrays like below:

- Start from index 1(1-based indexing).
- If current value is not zero, jump to `index * 2`.
- Repeat step 2 if current index value is not zero.
- If current index value is zero, iterate one by one from last non zero index to find value of `n`.

**Pseudocode:**

```
index = 1
prev = 1
while index <= arr.length and arr[index - 1] != 0:
    prev = index
    index = index * 2

while prev <= arr.length and arr[prev - 1] != 0
    prev++
```

The below linear run will be minimal as you have reached the last value of `n` in `log n`
time.
If `binarySearch` routine is already provided, then you can just do `binarySearch(A, k, 0, prev - 1)` to get the final answer.

Comment: you can improve it and make it binary search instead start at 0 double it if value is bigger move forward else move back

Comment: @ShubhamSrivastava Yes, we can avoid doing it twice.

Comment: Checkout my answer it is modification of your approach

Comment: This answer is wrong as it runs in O(n), not in O(log n).

Comment: @MoB. Any proof?

Comment: @nice_dev Well, you're iterating from the last non-zero index (`index/2`) up to the current index. But `index - index/2 = index/2 = O(index) = O(n)`.

Comment: @MoB. No. Note that the `n` here is different from actual array size as it is a sparse array. Say you have an array of size 100 and  say last non zero value is at 10. Then, my index will go to 16 which is a non zero value and prev will be at 8 and we will iterate one by one till 10 from 8. This doesn't make it linear but rather logarithmic.

Comment: This is not logarithmic, it's linear, as I have explained above. The worst-case happens if `n` is of the form `2^k - 1`. Then your last index will jump to `2^k`, and you have to iterate between `2^(k-1)` and `2^k`, which is `n/2`.

Comment: @MoB. You are confusing between `n` and difference between 2 values of power of 2.

Comment: @nice_dev Consider the following questions: (1) What is `n`? (Answer: the index of the left-most integer > 0). (2) What is the number of steps you have to iterate through in your second while loop? (Answer: `index - prev`) (3) What is `index - prev` in the worst-case? (Answer: `n/2` if `n` is of the form `2^k - 1`.) (4) What is the overall time complexity? (Answer: `O(n)`) Which of these statements do you not agree with?